# Gradle - Configure tests includes from property file

Tags: gradle, testng, build.gradle

I've got a Java project build with Gradle and a property file that contains custom configuration for my testing framework (amount of thread to use, test environment url, custom username & password for those environments, etc...).

I'm facing an issue related to using properties from that file that I can't figure out:

- if my Test task `include '**/*Test.class'`, all tests are running as expected.
- if my Test task `include '**/MyTest.class'`, only that test is running as expected.
- if my Test task `include readProperty()`, the task is skipped as NO-SOURCE. <- this is the part I can't understand - as the readProperty return the correct value.

*Let's get into details:*

This is how the property is defined in a `my.property` file:

```
testng.class.includes='**/MyTest.class'
```

This is what the `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream(projectDir.toString() + '/common.properties'))

def testsToRunWorking(p) {
  String t = 'MyTest.class'
  println "Tests = $t"
  return t ? t : '**/*Test.class'
}

def testsToRunNotWorking(p) {
  String t = getProperty(p, "testng.class.includes")
  println "Tests = $t"
  return t ? t : '**/*Test.class'
}

task testCustom(type: Test) {
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

  classpath = configurations.customTest + sourceSets.customTest.output
  include testsToRunNotWorking(props) ///< Does not work!
  // include testsToRunWorking(props) ///< Works!

  useTestNG()
}
```

*In terms of debugging:*

- The `println` properly return the value I expect, even when the testCustom task doesn't do what I would expect.
- I tried adding a `dependsOn` task just to print the content of `testCustom.configure { println $includes }` which looks correct as well.
- `--info`

  ```
  Tests = '**/MyTest.class'
  :clean
  :compileCustomTestJava - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
  :processCustomTestResources
  :customTestClasses
  :testCustom NO-SOURCE
  ```

The core of the issue seems to be coming from the fact that I'm reading that value from property. I hard coded inside the `build.gradle` everything works as expected. If read from a property file - build stops with a `NO-SOURCE` statement.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using quotation marks in the values of your property files. Everything that comes after the assignment sign in a property file is used as value, so the quotation marks remain in the string. They are printed in your output `Tests = '**/MyTest.class'`. On the other hand, if you define a string in your (Groovy) code with quotation marks, they are not included in the string. Therefor, the passed strings are not the same.

Remove the quotation marks from your property file(s) and everything should work, since the class files will match your string without the quotation marks.

Comment: Gosh thanks a lot @lu.koerfer
This is definitely something that we looked at hundred of times over the last week without even noticing it. Looks obvious now.
Guess that's why it's always worth having a second pair of eyes on something.
Ty!